# SQLite y C# como conectar

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, ms-access, migration

hice una aplicación de escritorio con c# pero use por primera vez SQLite en local para evitar el problema de Access, esta aplicación la debo instalar en el equipo de un cliente, pero no me ha dejado cargar la base de datos me ha mandado error 52 y 50, entonces mi pregunta es, cual es la mejor manera de mover mi aplicación con la base de datos MSQLite y que cargue los datos

Gracias!

Comment: Yo he movido aplicaciones .net con SQLite sin problemas, solo copiando y pegando la carpeta. Si tú tienes un problema, posiblemente es que la ruta del SQLite (lo que vendría siendo su connection string) no está bien puesto. El típico problema de rutas relativas

Comment: tengo este string @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLocalDB;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\MiDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Ahí no tienes un archivo de SQLite, eso tiene cara de ser SQL Compact Edition. Yo en un proyecto tengo esto de connection string "Data Source=db/datos.db". Luego al mismo nivel de carpeta donde está el .exe tengo una carpeta db y adentro datos.db. Y como te decía arriba puedo mover la aplicación de carpeta y/o de dispositivos sin problemas

Comment: tienes razón, me confundi con otro proyecto, lo que tengo es sqlexpress local, por eso tengo una bd tipo mdf, tu sabras como solucionar? una disculpa por la confusion

Comment: Lo primero que yo probaría es dejar MiDB.mdf en la misma carpeta del .exe y el connection string dejarlo de esta manera "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLocalDB;AttachDbFileName=MiDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True".

Comment: Acabo de hacer ese metodo, pero al correrlo en mi equipo me manda un error: Error al intentar adjuntar una BD con nombre automático para el archivo MiDB.mdf. Existe una base de datos con el mismo nombre, o el archivo especificado no se puede abrir, o se encuentra el recurso compartido UNC

Comment: Lo corriste en tu equipo desde visual studio (presionando ejecutar) ?? o desde el .exe?

Comment: de ambas formas y sale el mismo error